# how to use dialog flow API using Python and make your customised chat-bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, google-api, dialogflow-es

I am very new to dialog flow. I want to make a customised chat-bot using dialog flow V2 with calling API using python . How can i do this please suggest some steps and how i should get in start with it.

Comment: Start with their [official tutorial](https://dialogflow.com/docs/getting-started). Thereafter, if you have *specific* questions you can post them on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The Dialogflow Python client library documentation would be a good place to start.

See the following links for some guidance:

- https://dialogflow-python-client-v2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
- https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/quickstart-api#detect-intent-text-python
- https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/tutorials/build-an-agent/

Comment: The documentation is a joke.